# Channel.messageReceived event in Netty

Tags: java, netty

In a TCP based server-client model using Netty Channels , is there any correspondence between the number of `Channel.write()` from the server and the corresponding `Channel.messageReceived()` on the receiving client ? If I do a 10 `writes()` on the sender  , does it mean the `messageReceived()` will be invoked 10 times on the listening client ? or Netty can aggregate the sent data ( from the `write()`s on the sender ) into more or less number of `messageReceived()` events on the client  ? Is there a way to configure this behaviour in Netty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not guaranteed that you have a 1:1 mapping for your Channel.write(..) and messageReceived calls. You need to use some FrameDecoder subclass (maybe write your own)  which will buffer the ChannelBuffer until you receive enough data to dispatch your message to the next ChannelHandlers in the ChannelPipeline on the Server.

Netty already ships with some ready to use FrameDecoder implementations like The DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder (for example) which will take care to buffer the data until it receive a Delimiter and then dispatch it to the next handlers in the ChannelPipeline.

See [1] for more details.

[1] http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/FrameDecoder.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do this, but you'll have to give us more in order to do anything else.